# Set is not being reasigned between function calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, set

In my case I try to pass a set between recursive function calls and updating it. By passing it explicitly everytime as a parameter I want the set to keep updating, during the recursion.

For a new call I do not pass the set a a parameter explicity and expect that refence of `res_set` will redirected to an empty set object. But upon multiple calls to the function, the set is being updated as if  `res_set = set()` is not there.

```
 def some_recursion_withset(i, res_set = set()):
        res_set.add(random())
        if i > 0:
            i -= 1
            print(res_set)
            some_recursion_withset(i, res_set)
        return res_set

    some_recursion_withset(3)
    some_recursion_withset(1)
```

Here output is:

```
{0.12513618559206574}
{0.12513618559206574, 0.8224507177489353}
{0.12513618559206574, 0.8224507177489353, 0.7157637106872556}
{0.12513618559206574, 0.8224507177489353, 0.6921901499074943, 0.7157637106872556, 0.8116969360080692}
```

Reducing to a minimal working example, why in this case `res_set = set()` is being ignored?

```
from random import random

def some_func_withset(res_set = set()):
    res_set.add(random())
    return res_set

print(some_func_withset())
print(some_func_withset())
print(some_func_withset())
```

in this case the output is:

```
{0.9691623786355451}
{0.9691623786355451, 0.37884137576633103}
{0.9691623786355451, 0.37884137576633103, 0.4482797349507742}
```

**I am mostly interested in understanding this behavior and also some good practices to implement the first recursive part.**

Comment: Are you sure you're understanding `res_set = set()` correctly? What you're saying there is 'if I pass a `res_set` argument in then use it, if not, then use `set()`. It doesn't mean create a new set each time you call it, it just means use a new set as a default if it isn't passed to the function. https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-optional-arguments/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html):

> The default value is evaluated only once. This makes a difference when
> the
> default is a mutable object such as a list, dictionary, or instances of most
> classes. For example, the following function accumulates the arguments passed to
> it on subsequent calls:

The `res_set = set()` is only evaluated once, and that is the default argument, in your case a set object. When you use the function with the default argument you are always getting the same set object, and since you keep updating it, the set is growing with all the values you insert.

A solution to your problem is to use an immutable object as canary, and then check if your argument is this canary. Then create a new set if that is the case. Using `None` in this case is a convention for Python programmers:

```
def some_func_withset(res_set = None):
    if res_set is None:
        res_set = set()
    res_set.add(random())
    return res_set
```

Comment: so If i understand correctly, the best way to achieve recursive functionality I wanted is ("according to the manual"):

`def f(some_recursion_withset, res_set = None):` and check if `res_set` is `None`

Comment: Exactly. Please note that the test using `is` tests for object identity. Since there is only one `None` object for your Python instance, which is inserted whenever `None` is used, you can use `is` to see if the argument is this one `None` object or some other object.

Comment: It worked. Thank you a lot for your help :)